# Setting username in steam OpenID authentication with Django Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, steam

I'm trying to configure a new django application to use Steam's OpenID authentication.

The issue i'm running into is that when a new user sign's in (no form to allow them to customize username/specify email address) the something (either allauth or django.contrib.auth) defaults their User object's username to `user`.  That field is unique... so a 2nd user can't login.  I can't figure out what/where the new user object is created so we can customize that field.  We want it to pull from extra_data['personaname']) ideally.

I've traced it down to somewhere between `allauth.socialaccount.adapter.populate_user` and `allauth.account.utils.user_username`.

Populate user is called only once, and printing `locals()` there shows the `<User: Steam Username>`. but user_username is called five times, and the first is `Steam Username`, but the last is with `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating my own User model which solves this issue.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Player(PermissionsMixin):
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=128, unique=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS=()
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'

    is_active = True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
         return False

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
         return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
         return self.is_superuser

    @property
    def steam_id(self):
         return self.steam_account.uid

    @property
    def steam_account(self):
         return self.socialaccount_set.get(provider='steam')

    def set_unusable_password(self):
         """
         This only exists for allauth.
         """
         pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .models import Player

@admin.register(Player)
class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('last_login','date_joined')
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    )
    list_display = ('username', 'steam_id', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'steam_id')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser', 'groups')
    ordering = ('username','last_login', 'date_joined')
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```